# form validating fails

Tags: javascript, validation

I have a form and below is code
And when submit is clicked it returns `true` rather that displaying the 
`textfiled` to empty, it should give some error.

Its a simple form validation

html

```
<form name="rt-form2"  method="post" onsubmit="return validateform();">
<input type="text" value="Name" name="name2" id="name1"><br>

<input type="text" value="Email" name="Email" id="Email1"><br>

<input type="text" value="Phone Number" name="phone" id="phone1"><br>

<input type="submit" value="submit" name="submitm" class="submit-btn">
</form>
```

and javascript validation

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function validateform(){
 alert("Submit button is clicked");


     if(document.rt-form2.name2.value.length < 1) {
        alert("Enter name");
        return false;
     }
     else {
        alert("Submitting");
        return true;
    }


}

</script>
```

Comment: does document.rt-form2.name2.value.length selector even work ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dude your script is correct. Just remove the **hyphen** from your form name and you're good to go!

Answer (score 1):

I reran this and it seem that the error came from the name of the form. Using the '-' within the javascript was throwing errors. Once I switched to an '_' it seem to work fine.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kwelch/Y7j8N/)

I have done the same thing with jQuery that allows you to enter a default value and also validates all field with the class `required`. It is only slightly more complex because it validates that default value has been changed and also clears the field when it is selected.

[my Validation](http://jsfiddle.net/kwelch/T2qwh/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<body>
    <head>    
<script type="text/javascript">
function validateform()
{
    alert("Submit button is clicked");
    var namelength = document.formulari.name2.value.length;
    if(namelength < 1)
    {
        alert("Enter name");
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        alert("Submitting");
            return true;
    }
}

</script>
    </head>
<form name="formulari"  method="post" onsubmit="return validateform();">
<input type="text" name="name2" id="name2"><br>

<input type="text"  name="Email" id="Email1"><br>

<input type="text"  name="phone" id="phone1"><br>

<input type="submit" value="submit" name="submitm" class="submit-btn">
</form>
</body>
```

If by default you have a value in the field (`value="Name"`) it won't launch the "empty" error. Because is getting that default value. 
**EDIT**: I forgot to add that you have to chance the name of the form name. As I did in my code below.

Comment: Whoever did the downvote, could he explain why so I can improve in my next answers?

Answer (score 0):

```
    function validateForm()
        {
        var x=document.forms["formElem"]["name"].value;
        if (x==null || x=="" || x=="Name")
          {
          alert("All fields must be filled out");
          return false;
          }

         var x=document.forms["formElem"]["hnumber"].value;
        if (x==null || x=="" || x=="Phone")
          {
          alert("All fields must be filled out");
          return false;
          }

         var x=document.forms["formElem"]["mnumber"].value;
        if (x==null || x=="")
          {
          alert("All fields must be filled out");
          return false;
          }

          alert('Thanks for applying. Someone from HR will contact you shortly.');
    }
```

This is a really simple script that I use.